# Using jQuery Mobile swipe transitions distorting backgound image on iOS, except when reversed

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I have a multi page jQuery Mobile (1.40, with jQuery 1.10.2) page, like below. On iOS, the transition 'right' to the next page distorts the background image briefly. The same transition 'left' works as expected. It seems to work normally on Safari on Mac.

See this video to see what's happening :- http://cl.ly/3C1k3y1k2I0C/download/jQuery%20Mobile%20issue.mp4

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" class="welcome" id="welcome1">

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    <h2 class="logo">Page 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>

    <div class="dots-container">
      <ul class="dots">
        <li class="on"><a href="#welcome1" data-transition="slide">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#welcome2" data-transition="slide">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#welcome3" data-transition="slide">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->



<div data-role="page" class="welcome" id="welcome2">

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>

    <div class="dots-container">
      <ul class="dots">
        <li><a href="#welcome1" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">1</a></li>
        <li class="on"><a href="#welcome2" data-transition="slide">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#welcome3" data-transition="slide">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->



<div data-role="page" class="welcome" id="welcome3">

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    <h2>Get Started</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>

    <div class="dots-container">
      <ul class="dots">
        <li><a href="#welcome1" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#welcome2" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">2</a></li>
        <li class="on"><a href="#welcome3" data-transition="slide">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

CSS:

```
[data-role=page].welcome {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size:100%;
}
[data-role=page]#welcome1 {
  background-image: url('images/welcome1.jpg');
}
[data-role=page]#welcome2 {
  background-image: url('images/welcome2.jpg');
}
[data-role=page]#welcome3{
  background-image: url('images/welcome3.jpg');
}
```

Comment: You probably just need to pre-load the images so they are already on the client by the time the user swipes. Have a look at this for some ideas: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: Hm, but it's not that they're not loaded. The briefly visible part is approx. the top left quarter of the image. The same thing occurs if you then page away and then back, so preloading I presume couldn't be an issue.